# How to implement Stash Pull request 'Merge' button

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request, bitbucket-server

In an Atlassian-Stash system, I have a repository with both pre-receive and post-receive hooks implemented but now the developers started to use the pull request (which is great!) but clicking 'Merge' button skips the logic that is in the pre- and post-receive hooks (which is blocking the merge is some cases and activating a build in the post-receive).
How can I implement the same logic for the 'Merge' button? (or make it activates the hooks?)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you have to use external plugin to do it.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.ngs.stash.externalhooks.external-hooks/server/overview

Im a stash administrator and this is the way i control and catch and process the commits.

Here is a snapshot of few of the hooks in stash which does what you need:

[image]

Comment: 1. Atlassian Stash v3.2.4 is installed on my system and it can't find the suggested Add On which is probably can be used only in later versions (which were released as 'BitBacket' not 'Stash'
2. @codeWizard, Are you sure you can implement the 'Merge' button event as I need?

Comment: OK, I just did it, but I've got 'This add-on is not compatible with your Stash instance' massage to I can't use it without upgrade which I'm not sure will be performed soon.

Comment: Anyway, as I've wrote in the first comment - it doesn't implementing the PR 'Merge' button so it is not good for me anyway

Comment: Its too long to explain how stash works (sync/async hooks) and the way to achieve what you want is via those plugins. This is how im using it in our company

Comment: I know how hooks are implemented and used but I'm not sure I understand what hooks does the 'pull requests Merge button' is activating

Comment: At last I've tried the above 'External Hooks' add on but it is odd since clicking the 'Merge' button activates only the script that is configured in the 'External Async Post Receive Hook' hook (which is nice to have) but is not activating the script that is configured in the 'External Pre Receive Hook' (which has the more important code for my usage).
@codeWizard, can you explain this?